# A license free for free software but a fee for commercial software?

Tags: licensing

I am looking for a license that allows developers who release their software freely/non-commercially use my software without any cost, but those who releases commercial software needs to buy a license. I've been looking at the GNU licenses but they all seem to be free for both commercial and non-commercial use.

What are the commonly used licenses in my case?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but you can release your software with a dual-licensing. This is what e.g. MySQL if I'm not mistaken (and several other GPL licensed software)

Comment: But you need to be careful to select a open source license with enough restrictions that makes commercial use not viable. E.g. iText used GPL but this allows generating documents (or server use in general) without open-sourcing your product. That is why they switched to AGPL after 2.1.7 which forces user to open-source their applications even when only distributing generated documents (PDF in this case).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210) about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be no general answer to your question, you either do this by creating your own software license (which can not be free as in [The Free Software Definition](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) because you restrict commercial use) or you can try to achieve something similar with dual licensing as following:

The public and freely available software is available under a free software license with strong copyleft like the [GNU Affero General Public License (AGPL)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html). Any entity making use of the software must publish the source and changes to all it's users under the same license (reciprocal, ASP loophole closed).

You can even make the software practicable incompatible with mostly any open source software by choosing the [Open Software License (OSL)](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0). It's incompatible in this sense with most of the existing open source software (first hand GPL which covers the largest share of open source code, but also many others) and has strong copyleft by usage (communication of the work even), so it's pretty limiting.

You would actually signal: don't use the free version - a somewhat morally questionable move.

As (and if) this is not fitting for the type of commercial use you ask about, then you can offer a second license for commercial use. If someone complains you can just tell them, hey it's free software. Bad move, but probably working. Ask your lawyer for the details, this variant might not be what you're looking for, you won't do the free software community a favor.

Instead you need to find out what you actually want to do. Restrict commercial use or not. After you've done that, talk with a lawyer to create a fitting software license for your work.